# Finding how many times a substring appears in a given string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, find

```
s = 'This is a bad bad example'
sub = 'bad'

start = 0
count = 0
while True:
    start = s.find(sub,start) + 1
    if start >= 0:
        count = count+1
    else:
        break

print 'The number of times bad appears in the given string is: ' + str(count)
```

This is what I have tried. I have tried to debug it on my own but I am just not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Am I using the `find()` function incorrectly?

Comment: Oh! and the code results in an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard, and the best part is that python removes the need to loop over everything!

Try this:

```
>>> a = "this is a bad bad example"
>>> a.count('bad')
2
```

`a.count(b)` returns the number of occurrences of `b` in string or list `a`.

**EDIT**
To address your code:

```
while True:
    start = s.find(sub,start) + 1
    if start >= 0:
        count = count+1
    else:
        break
```

You are using `find()` correctly, but when there are not more `bad`s to be found it will return `-1`, which you then add one to (also correctly, due to 0-indexing) BUT you then check `start >= 0` which will ALWAYS return true because -1 (a false result) will become 0 (a positive result)

Try this:

```
start = -1 # start at -1 now, you'll see why...
while True:
    start = s.find(sub,start + 1)
    if start >= 0:
        count = count+1
    else:
        break
```

So you account for off-by-one errors in the `find()` call rather than storing it in your termination condition.  Better yet:

```
while start >= 0:
    start = s.find(sub,start+1)
    count += 1
```

Comment: ok wow! Didn't knew about the count() function. but just for the sake of it - can we do it my way.I mean I still want to know where I was going wrong @Will

Comment: you can use a for loop and `s.split()` to iterate through the list, and every time an item matches your substring, increment count. but I like Will's way a lot better.

Comment: I think `.count()` is the most pythonic.  It was designed for this exact use :)

Comment: i agree @Will..And I am goig to use that..I found the solution though..in my code if I change `if start >=0:` to `start>0` it will work fine...In your solution though if the substring is not present in the s, it will still give 1 as output...Thanx for your valuable inputs though...I am going to tick your first answer :-)

Comment: @ArshdeepSinghBakshi I'm glad, you'll save yourself a headache.  Good catch on the bug in my code, that's why `count()` is so useful!

Comment: I take it back...I missed the `start = -1` part...Your solution is correct too...

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think count works as you might expect if the substrings "overlap". For example:

```
s1="dadad"
s2='dadsdad'

sub="dad"

s1.count(sub) #1
s2.count(sub) #2
```

This is how I worked around it:

```
def overlapping_substring_count(string,sub_string):
    l=len(sub_string)
    count=0
    for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)+1):
        if(string[i:i+len(sub_string)] == sub_string ):      
            count+=1
    return count  

s1='dadad'
s2="dad"

print(overlapping_substring_count(s1,s2))
```

Comment: Can you give the output also

Comment: This outputs 2, counting both the "dad" sub strings even through the second one starts with the letter that ends the first one